# Menu Item on/off day night mode

Tags: java, android, menuitem

It is necessary that the menu item on or off the day and night modes instead of the  switche. Please help with the function. When the app is in the day mode, the user selects the item menu of the Day/Night mode from the menu. It is ok, night mode is on, but when the same item is selected from the night mode, there is no change, and it should return to the day mode. Please help me.

```java
boolean isNight = true;
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.day_night:
        if (Button.isChecked()) {
            //display warning message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.warning_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            if (isNight) {
                getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: where is this code? if you initialize `isNight` to true, then it will be true every time this code is executed. The `MODE_NIGHT_NO` is not reachable.

Comment: I would like to help you, but I need to know what exactly you want to do. Do you want a button that activates and deactivates night mode? Why are you showing a `Toast` when the button is checked? And where is this code, in the `onClick` button event?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, you are very kind, I added `!isNight` and changed `isNight = false;` and now works. thank you very much

Comment: if you set `isNight = false` and then you test `if (!isNight)` then, you will not be able to change to `MODE_NIGHT_YES`.

Comment: True, you are right, what in that case? :( I have to click twice on the menu item Day / Night mode to switch from day to night mode, and when in the night mode I click once and enter the day mode without any problems.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable (outside `onOptionsItemSelected`)

```
boolean isNight;  // by default, isNight = false
```

Then in your `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.day_night:
        if (!isNight) {
            getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            isNight = true;
        } else {
            getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            isNight = false;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have to click twice on the menu item Day / Night mode to switch from night to day mode, and when in the day mode I click once and enter the night mode without any problems. I testetd on emulator and in my cell phone whit your code. Why?

Comment: The answer was useful, but there is still a problem, please take a look at my comment. Thank you.